# Tiled elements start halfway through my parent element instead of starting at the left side of the parent element

Tags: html, css

**Description**: I have a parent element which contains a width of 100%. Then, each element within the element has a width of 25% and are each floated left. The style works up to the fifth element where it is supposed to be merged to the second line of the page however it does so, but starts halfway through the page instead of where the first element starts.

**URL**: [Page experiencing the problem](https://peachcobbler.app/extensions/)

Here is what the ideal layout should look like: [Ideal Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdNsj.png)

Versus what is currently looking like: [What it actually looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4XOC.png)

My browser is Chrome, my laptop is a Macbook Pro 13-inch.

Each element contains the class `col-3` and the parent element has `col-12`. Here is the css for each:

```
  .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-12 {width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Chrome Dev Tools, i was able to make the below changes, and it worked. Can you let me know if that helps?

```
[class*="col-"] {
width: 100%;
/* float: left; */
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

[image]

Comment: It fixes the griding system, but then everything else (such as "Our Network") becomes offset.

Comment: The link appears to be functioning properly now. It seems that the answer was applied to the .extensions-content [class*="col-"] class in the css.

Comment: So it seems like we found a solution, great, but can you explain why the float: left does not work with this specific tiling?

Comment: I am still pretty new with this, so I may not be able to answer that part fully. But, from what I understand, float seems to be meant for text in situations where the text needs direction as to how it should wrap around other elements (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float). Float also has no effect on either absolutely positioned elements, or Float elements. If I had to guess, when you were initially using the Float property, there was some sort of invisible padding/border/margin that the boxes were attempting to wrap around.

Comment: However, the Flex (flexbox) display property has its own set of classes for spacing and alignment to include: align-content, align-items, align-self, flex, flex-basis, flex-direction, flex-flow, flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-wrap, justify-content, order. Which can all assist you far better than Float can, and especially in the situation you are working with on your site.